Getting function not defined error while rendering in ejs
I'm trying to render some elements based on data from backend in an ejs file:
<% data.forEach(data => { %>
                <div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text"><%= data.something %></p>
                                <span><%= getTimeElapsed(data.dateSubmit) %></span>

                        </div>
                </div>
<% }); %>

But I keep getting an error on the span line that the function doesn't exist. If I remove the span line, the file renders fine without any errors and I have checked in console that I can call that function.
I've tried different things, like adding the function in script tag in the file itself but still get the same error.
I'm not sure why the javascript file isn't present for the html. Any help is appreciated.
I have the javascript linked in the head tag:
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="/javascripts/elapsedtime.js"></script>
</head>

Here's my elapsedtime.js file:
function getTimeElapsed(submitdate) {
    // Converting into date object
    var submitteddate = new Date(submitdate);
    // Current time
    var currentDate = new Date();

    // Calculating time difference
    return currentDate - plantDate;
}

This code is present on the router file that routes to the ejs where I'm rendering the data.
router.get('/main', function(req, res, next) {
  let res = train.getAll()
  res.then(trains => {
    let train = JSON.parse(trains);
    res.render('main', { title: 'View All Plants', data: train});
  })
});


It's not shown how ejs is rendered. Does this happen on client or server side? getTimeElapsed needs to be defined on the same side and explicitly provided to ejs

@EstusFlask I've added the route code that passes on the data to the ejs. Do I need to pass the getTimeElapsed function while rendering the page? Also I am able to run the function if it's in the ejs file within <% %> code, does this mean that I will need getTimeElapsed on the server side?

@EstusFlask Thank you, I was able to pass the function from server side and I don't get any errors now.
